# How to add unique constraint on a property inherited from Role class in DevExpres, Xpo?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xpo

I have a class which inherits Role class.

```
 public class WMSRole : Role
{
    //....some properties/relationships
}
```

As Role inherits RoleBase and last class has Name property, how could I define this unique rule on Name?

Later update:

this is the solution I've succeeded to implement, edit the Designed.Diffs(through model designer)

```
 <Validation>
    <Rules>
      <RuleUniqueValue Id="WmsRole Name Should be Unique" TargetContextIDs="Save" TargetCollectionOwnerType="" TargetCollectionPropertyName="" TargetPropertyName="Name" TargetType="Davanti.WMS.Core.Model.Authorisation.WMSRole" IsNewNode="True" />
      <RuleRequiredField Id="WmsRole Name is Required" TargetContextIDs="Save" TargetCollectionOwnerType="" TargetCollectionPropertyName="" TargetPropertyName="Name" TargetType="Davanti.WMS.Core.Model.Authorisation.WMSRole" IsNewNode="True" />
    </Rules>
  </Validation>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think that you should hide the inherited property if you want to add some constraints just on this one

```
private string name;
        public static string PropertyName = "Name";
       new public string Name
        {
            get { return Name; }
            set { Name = value; }
        }
```

Comment: I've never tried that way... in the end what I've done was to add unique constraint from designer which edited my designed.diffs file.

Comment: "see updated question" - for the solution I was talking about

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RuleCombinationOfPropertiesIsUnique` which is a class attribute rather than a property attribute.

```
[RuleCombinationOfPropertiesIsUnique("RoleUniqueName", DefaultContexts.Save, "Name")]
public class MyRole : Role {   
    public MyRole(Session session) : base(session) { }
    // etc...   
}
```

Or for anything more complex, you have the `RuleFromBoolProperty` attribute. See the documentation [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/clsDevExpressPersistentValidationRuleFromBoolPropertyAttributetopic).

E.g.,

```
[RuleFromBoolProperty("RoleUniqueName", DefaultContexts.Save, 
  "Role with this Name already exists", UsedProperties = "Name")]
public bool IsNameUnique {
      //... 
}
```